# How convert this htaacees for web.config?

Tags: .htaccess

please convert this htacees for web.config

```js
    <Files ~ "^.*\.(php|php*|cgi|pl|phtml|shtml|sql|asp|aspx)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
RemoveType .php .php* .phtml .pl .cgi .asp .aspx .sql
```

this htacces is for upload script kleeja for safe

url rewrite in iss can not convert this

thanks

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any logic in this `web.config`, a `.htaccess` does not seem neccessary

Comment: this htaccess is for Prevent of upload shell to folder uploadcenter

Comment: in iis how prevent of upload shell whit web.config ?